Dismiss/Cancel button with auto login flow using Credential Manager on Android
In the old google one tap flow on Android, there was a dismiss button which can cancel the "auto login" flow once the auto login is initiated. However, when using Android credential manager, there is no dismiss or cancel button to cancel the "auto login" flow once it is initiated.
I looked into the public api to find any related method which enables such a dismiss button. Is there any option to enable which allows this?
Old Flow With Dismiss Button
New Credential Manager Flow
Credentials library version used: 1.2.2

Isn't there the system back button right there on the bottom of your screen? Are you saying that the universal signal to go back doesn't work when that dialog is open?

Currently, you can use the Back button/gesture to cancel the flow when that transient confirmation page is shown. Do you feel having an explicit "Cancel" button will help?

For sure, having an explicit cancel button helps a lot. Especially when we are migrating from old bottom sheet to the new credential manager bottom sheet, people who have used the old bottom sheet in the past will be looking for the cancel button and will not be able to find it and hence will not be happy.

Ok, thanks for the feedback. I'll see if we can put that back there.
